# How can I change the layout of a dialogFragment when a softKeyboard is opened?

Tags: java, android

I've got a quite big `dialogFragment`, with 5 `editText`'s, and some text, to explain what should be filled in. This `dialogFragment` fits on the screen perfectly fine, until the keyboard is opened. To compensate this, I would like to hide/remove the explanatory text while the keyboard is open.
The text is shown in a `textView` and in the dialog's `message`.
I know it's not simple to do something when the keyboard is opened/closed, but with some hacks, I hope it's doable.

So: How can I change the layout of the `dialogFragment` based on the state of the keyboard?

[image]

[image]

*Click either image to view a bigger version*

---

Also, as you can see in the second image, the clock / icons in the notification area (or whatever it's called these days) are showing through the `dialogFragment`. It would be lovely if that could be prevented too, for learning purposes, but that's not the most important part.

Comment: you can have event of is keyboard showing in the activity and based on that you can do appropriate work, also you can set adjustResize|adjustSpan etc in your manifest file which will adjust UI when keyboard is open.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the 'is keyboard showing' event you're talking about? I can't find anything detailed on it on the web.